# Fatal error: Call to undefined function logged_in()

Tags: php, function, session, authentication, undefined

I made a login script, when I want to check when the user is logged in, I use the function logged_in(), which consists of:

```
function logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the session is set here:

```
else if ($login === true)
        {
            echo 'Login success.';
            include 'include/aside.php';
            include 'include/footer.php';
            $userid = id_from_username($username);
            $usernameforsession = username_from_id($userid);
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userid;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $usernameforsession;
            header( "refresh:2;url=index.php");
            exit();
        }
```

And this is an example of me using it in 'index.php':

```
if(logged_in() === true)
{
    echo 'Site content when user is logged in.';
} else if(logged_in() === false)
{
    include 'include/widgets/register.php'; //registration form
}
```

And yes, the function is included in every page.
I made this function so it should work...
Why isn't it working?

Comment: Error doesn't say that function is not working. It says, it IS NOT INCLUDED. So start from there.

Comment: In what page do you define the function logged_in()? Where is that included above the first call in index.php?

Comment: I said it IS included, and I'm sure about this.
I have an init.php file that includes all the necessary pages with all the functions:
init.php:
<?
session_start();

error_reporting(1); //not showing error reports like mysql errors. for debug make it 1

require 'database/connect.php';

require 'functions/general.php';

require 'functions/users.php';


in users.php there is the logged_in() function.

Comment: And where does this session check occur in relation to the `logged_in()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code:

```
if(logged_in() === true)
```

With this code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
```

That cuts out all the middlemen.

Comment: Now there is absolutely no display. White blank page. (Can't do anything, can't log in.)

Comment: Add this line before it `error_reporting(-1);`. That will give you an error message to let you know what the problem is.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and this solution worked, but why wouldn't the function work either?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have listed quite a bit of code, are you sure you are including `session_start();` at the top of each page? You need to call this before you do anything at all with the session variables.

The second thing is that the error message is showing that the function isn't defined - are you sure you have it either in the source for the page or as an include to the code that defines it on each page?

If you have it in a file called 'functs.php', you need to `include()` it in every page that will make a call to that function.

Comment: Yes I am calling it in the start of each page.

Comment: @user1593037 Are you certain you are including it in each page that calls the function?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in the comments on the post above ^^.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that the declaration is being included on every page, then I would suggest that you check to make sure the function is not declared as a method inside an object.

Comment: look at where the function is declared, check above to make sure there is no object declaration such as "class xxx"

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function" is very explicit, the script can't find the function. To test try including the users.php directly before you call logged_in(). I don't see how session_start is going to affect anything regarding that error message.. Perhaps make sure that nothing is being echoed to the browser before the session_start